# Getting error when installing app from Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Running app from Android studio on my device for testing is working fine. But when I am trying to install same app from Google Play, which is published under beta version getting error. I have uninstalled unsigned .apk from the device but am still not able to install from Google Play.

Even cleared phone cache same result.

[image]

Comment: What error you getting ?

Comment: Error code (-505)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an error with the Google Play Store.

Go into your app menu, force stop the Google Play Store Service, Clear Data, log back in and try again.

Comment: Tried this many times but no solution. Still getting same problem. I think before i was installing unsigned APK and now trying to install signed from google play that why facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing with the same problem. It was happening in my case was because google play has conflicts with already installed version of another app with MAP_RECEIVE permissions. I don't know why. I wrote that a lot of peoples faced with the same problem with some kind of FACEBOOK permissions as well. But in my case I was't able to install release file as well and I was reading in adb logs what exactly happening.

I added `{applicationId}` in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:name="${applicationId}.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
```

That helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no issue with your code, you have to remove the google account from your device and clear the cache of google play services and google play store. Then restart your device and login with your google account and then try to install the application.

if this solution not working for you then there some issue with Marshmallow.Because some application not compatible with Marshmallow.

Comment: can you please tell me about your device version? @Nitinsood